# The Mean of the Range, IQR and SD? Will it give an interesting result?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What if we take the Mean of the three chief measures of spread, i.e Range, Interquartile range, and the Standard deviation?

Will it give us an "all-purpose" measure of spread that is very reliable, or will it just be counterproductive and give us something more unreliable?

Just curious.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the robust (IQ) with non robust measures of spread.

Comment: @Chinny84 Could you elaborate?

Comment: The IQ is more stable to extreme outliers - whilst range and sd is less so. Depending on what you are trying to measure.